# retrieve number from hex string in variable length

Tags: java, hex

I have a hex string format below:

```
2828287798519497FFFF9000 => 2828287798519497 (result)
1122334466667788996FFFF9000 => 1122334466667788996 (result)
```

which the id is length in between 16 – 19, where right most is fill with 0xF.

What is 0xF?

How can I get id number, wither it is 16, 17, 18 or 19 length from the hex string above?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear.  Please show explicitly what part of each hex string is the `id` you are looking for, and what you need to do with it. For example, do you need to extract the `id` to its own string? Do you need to convert it to a decimal value?  Also show what code you have written so far.

Comment: When you say "hex string format", do you mean literally a `String` containing hex digit characters?

Comment: Yes it is a hex string

Comment: So it looks like the results you want are everything except the `FFFF9000` at the end of each string, yes?

Answer (score 2):

[`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is for arbitrary precision integral math, and it has a constructor that takes a `String` and an `int` radix. `0xF` is the sixteenth value in base 16 (digits are the usual zero to nine of base-10 **and** the values A, B, C, D, E and F).

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("2828287798519497FFFF9000", 16));
System.out.println(new BigInteger("1122334466667788996FFFF9000", 16));
```

The base-10 representation of your two values is thus

```
12427948526435964620659200000
21719411700849473095611778568192
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not looking to convert into base 10, but to get this 2828287798519497FFFF9000 => 2828287798519497 (result)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples you gave, the ID number you want consists of all but the last eight characters of the given hex string (which are `FFFF9000` in both example cases).  In other words, a substring starting at the beginning of the string and extending up to, but not including, the eight-to-last character:

```
String h = "2828287798519497FFFF9000";
String id = h.substring(0, h.length()-8);
System.out.println(h + " => " + id);
```